# changing single vertex value

Tags: opengl

In my project I'd like to edit given vertex position which is already in GPU.
Do I need to reload whole model or there is an function to change needed vertex.

This is how I pass mesh to GPU

```
void Mesh3v3n2t::PassToGPU()
{
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 32*vertices.size(),vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, (void*)12);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, (void*)24);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*4, indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [glBufferSubData](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferSubData). You may want to rethink the `GL_STATIC_DRAW` usage hint if you're going to be doing this frequently, but it's not *necessary*.